# Как на одной форме разместить главную и подчинённую таблицу?

Tags: база-данных, access, ms-access

Чтобы при перемещении курсора по записям главной таблицы в подчинённой отображались только записи соответствующие полю "tb4_id".

Пример находится по ссылке
http://transfiles.ru/ecxdt

Answer (score 1):

Это стандартный функционал Акцесса. Главную таблицу делаете базовой для формы, для подчиненной создаете еще одну форму, помещаете ее на форму с главной таблицей как подформу и связываете по ключевому полю через свойства подформы (вкладка Данные, заполняете поля для связи).